# ajax response in web2py

Tags: python, ajax, jquery, web2py

i am working on adding ajax to comments in my webpage.
following are the functions and the view file

```
def normalajax():
    news=db(db.newsfeed.id>0).select(orderby=~db.newsfeed.created_on)
    return dict(news=news)

def new_post():
    form=SQLFORM(db.newsfeed)
    if form.accepts(request.vars, formname=None):
        news=db(db.newsfeed.created_by==auth.user_id).select(orderby=~db.newsfeed.created_on)
        return DIV(news)
    elif form.errors:
        return TABLE(*[TR(k, v) for k, v in form.errors.items()]) 


{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<form id="myform">
  <input name="body" id="body" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
 <script>$('textarea').css('width','600px').css('height','50px');</script>

<script>
jQuery('#myform').submit(function() {
  ajax('{{=URL('new_post')}}',
       ['body'], 'target');
  return false;
});

</script> 

<div id="target">
 {{for post in news:}}
 <div style="background: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 8px;">
 <h3>{{=db.auth_users[post.created_by].first_name}}</h3> On {{=post.created_on}}:
  {{=MARKMIN(post.body)}}

 </div>    
 {{pass}}

</div>
```

The problem is that, when i post a new comment, the entire div is replaced by the new content,without all the styling which i have given in the for loop

i have given the links of screenshots:
this is before posting comment:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=AFF5DF0EB4A5BCD5!122&authkey=!AFg6utSsGLyYRG4&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png

this is after posting comment:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=AFF5DF0EB4A5BCD5!123&authkey=!AJyroKLQLp5ssPs&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png

after posting comment, the ajax response replaces contents of div target, how do i access the response and display it like it is dislayed before posting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the page is in the browser, you cannot execute Python code on it. The Python code in your original template does not exist once the page is in the browser -- that has all been executed to generate pure HTML source code. When you submit the form, the `new_post` function returns `DIV(news)`, which gets converted to HTML. That HTML replaces the content of the "target" div on the page. When you generate an Ajax response, you have to generate the final HTML on the server and send that to the browser -- the browser does not do any template processing.

In any case, a better approach would probably be to use Ajax components. Not tested, but something like:

```
def news():
    return dict()

def news_list():
    if request.args(0) == 'user':
        query = db.newsfeed.created_by == auth.user_id
    else:
        query = db.newsfeed.id > 0
    news = db(query).select(orderby=~db.newsfeed.created_on)
    return dict(news=news)

def new_post():
    form = SQLFORM(db.newsfeed)
    if form.process().accepted:
        url = URL('default', 'news_list.load', args='user')
        response.js = "$.web2py.component('%s', target='news');" % url
    return dict(form=form)

In /views/default/news.html:

{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=LOAD('default', 'new_post.load', ajax=True)}}
{{=LOAD('default', 'news_list.load', ajax=True, target='news')}}

In /views/default/news_list.load:

{{for post in news:}}
 <div style="background: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 8px;">
 <h3>{{=post.created_by.first_name}}</h3> On {{=post.created_on}}:
  {{=MARKMIN(post.body)}}
{{pass}}

In /views/default/new_post.load:

{{=form}}
```

In the above code, news.html is the main page, and it contains two Ajax components -- one for the form, and one for the news list. Initially, the news list component loads all the news posts (you might consider limiting that or paginating if there are many posts). When the form is submitted, it returns some Javascript via `response.js`, which gets executed after a successful submission. The Javascript calls `$.web2py.component()` in the browser, which reloads the news list component in the "news" div by calling the `news_list()` function with "user" as a URL arg (the "user" arg is a flag that tells the `news_list()` function to return only the posts of the current user).

Comment: hey, i tried using the above code, but the new value is not getting displayed, although it is getting submitted and shows up when i reload the page, thanks for the help!...I wanted to ask one more thing, can we add a component inside another component, if we can then when the form inside the nested components gets submitted, will the outer component also get refreshed? ...Again, thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: The above code works fine for me (new value gets displayed immediately, as long as the created_by value is the id of the current logged in user). If you observe something different, it is likely because you have altered the code in some way. (Note, I did correct a few typos above, but they would have generated exceptions, not the behavior you observed.).

Comment: Yes, I believe you should be able to nest components, but when a form inside a nested component is submitted, it will not refresh the outer component. The above example is a better approach.

Comment: thanks...there is a small mistake in above code....web2py.component should be web2py_component...now its working!

Comment: Sorry, should be `$.web2py.component` or `jQuery.web2py.component`. `web2py_component` also works, but that is deprecated and available only for backward compatibility.

Comment: Is there any way to just append the comment without having to reload the existing comments (for example i have embedded videos in comments, when i add a comment, all the videos in previous comments also get reloaded).

Comment: Sure, but it will be more complicated. Upon submission, the returned Javascript should make a request to retrieve just the HTML for the new comment, and then you would need Javascript code to append that HTML to the current list of comments.

Answer (score 0):

apply same css to your Ajax response to get the same view

this css is missing from ajax reponse.

view this example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
})
 .done(function( result) {
 $( "#results" ).append( result); // or replace your "result" coming from server
});
```

Comment: but how do i access ajax response, it is replacing the contents of entire div?